# rounding big floating point numbers

Tags: python, numpy, rounding

I'm implementing Jacobian algorithm to find eigenvalue of a given matrix.My problem is with float numbers like 1.2335604410291751e+216.I can not round them.

I tried np.around and round functions but they didnt work.

Comment: `round(1.2335604410291751e+216)` work perfectly well. What does _not_ work?

Comment: round(1.2335604410291751e+216) just returns an int number!I want to round it to 5 decimal places.

Comment: Could you please provide the expected result and how you used `np.around` (and [edit] it into the question). Also note that `1.2335604410291751e+216` is a number with 217 (!) places in front of the decimal point (the `e` indicates it uses [Scientific (exponential) notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to only round *m* of a number in standard form (m × bⁿ) you can do it like this, for m, b, and n the number, the base, and the exponent, respectively:

```
import math

def round_(m, d, b = 10):
    n = math.floor(math.log(abs(m), b),)

    return float(round(m * (b ** (d - n))) * (b ** - (d - n)))
```

Some test outputs:

```
>>> print(round_(1.23456783456787434567e-22, 1))
1.2299999999999998e-22
>>> round_(-1.23456783456787434567e+159, 7)
-1.2345678e+159
>>> round_(1.23456783456787434567e+50, 6)
1.234568e+50
>>> round_(-0.23456783456787434567e+256, 5)
-2.34568e+255
>>> round_(1.23456783456787434567e+255, 4)
1.2346e+255
>>> round_(0.23456783456787434567e+272, 3)
2.346e+271
>>> round_(1.23456783456787434567e-23, 2)
1.235e-22
>>> round_(-1.23456783456787434567e+251, 1)
-1.2e+251
```

**Overflows may occur (See output #1)**.

Tested using Python 3.7.